# LED ceiling panels: driver with alexa/home automation capabilities

Tags: lighting

I have 3 LED ceiling lamps, unfortunately they're using some proprietary protocols for communication. The chip used in remote is PL51WT020:
[PL51WZ020 (PMicro website)](https://www.pmicro.com.cn/en/mcurf_/17.html)

Is there a way to control the lights using RaspberryPi (other then emulating remote keypresses)?

The lights have two LEDs (dimmable, warm-cold white LED and color LED)- is there any possibility to change the LED driver to one with Alexa built-in?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If you want to change the built-in driver it would be more useful to see that driver and the LEDs. Depending on the LEDs something like [this](https://www.cnx-software.com/2023/08/04/home-assistant-compatible-5-24v-led-strip-controller-sound-reactive-wled-firmware/) could be a solution, but we lack a lot of info.

Comment: please add the source of the pictures to your post ... **do not** add comment

Comment: @jsotola- thanks, I replaced the photo with photos taken by me, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Replace the controller in the panel with (as an example) *Electrodragon ESP32-C3 Mosfet Drive LED Controller*, and flash it with (for example) Tasmota firmware.

The "Electrodragon" deice has four MOSFET channels, so it can drive your CW, WW and two colors.

Tasmota has a Belkin emulator or Philips Hue that can be integrated with Alexa.

There are other devices and firmware that can do the same, so the above are just examples.